# Datastax java driver 4.0 configuration programmatically

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Is it still possible to configure a Cluster (like Datastax java driver 3.8 driver version) with the new 4.0 version. Or the only solution is to use a configuration file like in the documentation ? https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.0/manual/core/configuration/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to configure driver programmatically. Just follow the section ["" of driver documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/configuration/#programmatic-application-config).  You just need to define config loader using `DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder`, and then use it when building the `CqlSession`:

```java
DriverConfigLoader loader =
    DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder()
        .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .startProfile("slow")
        .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(30))
        .endProfile()
        .build();
CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder().withConfigLoader(loader).build();
```

Driver has a lot of options available, but as practice shows, it's ok to define many defaults in config file, and use loader only for something non-standard.

P.S. It's better to take driver 4.5 as it works with both OSS & DSE versions... Plus many improvements, like, reactive support, etc.